# Pegar o valor do atributo "data-" com jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Boa tarde, estou fazendo uma atividade de html + js(com jquery), preciso pegar o valor do atributo "data-" quando o botão for clicado. Segue o código:

html:

```
    <table id="table" class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Foto</td>
      <td>Produto</td>
      <td>Descrição</td>
      <td>Tipo</td>
      <td>Alocação</td>
      <td>Quantitativo</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="http://localhost:7304/storage/img/aa76a3cbb48e4c85836f9464fca46e15.jpg" class="images" width="100px" height="100px"></td>
      <td>Luva</td>
      <td>feitos para usar individualmente</td>
      <td>EPC</td>
      <td>Prateleira 2/Linha 1</td>
      <td data-name="1"><button type="button" class="quantitative-btn">Ver Quantitativo</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="http://localhost:7304/storage/img/QIpAROTIjsoZZgxlDFaHRRgmQa1ndhNI6DUjg12M.jpeg" class="images" width="100px" height="100px"></td>
      <td>print</td>
      <td>345tyuiop</td>
      <td>EPC</td>
      <td>Prateleira 1/Linha 1</td>
      <td data-name="2"><button type="button" class="quantitative-btn">Ver Quantitativo</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

js:

```
$(() => {
  $(document).on('click', '.quantitative-btn', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).parent().parent().find('td').data('name');
    alert(id);
  });
});
```

Quando o botão é clicado, ele aparece "null". Como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode tentar:

```
$('.quantitative-btn').on('click', function(){
     var name = $(this).parent().data('name');
     alert(name);
});
```

Comment: Olá Allex, no alert ele retorna "Undefined"...

Comment: Amigo, eu testei aqui e funcionou
Resultado: https://snipboard.io/G0BibL.jpg
Codigo: https://snipboard.io/rCMa1R.jpg

Comment: Tinha esquecido de apagar o cache da página na atualização, mas obrigado, funcionou.

Comment: disponha amigo.